# Correspond first line of arrays with second line VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a file that shows A song name on the first line, then the genre on the second, and the time on the third.

Example

```
All You Need is Love-Beatles
Rock
4.25
```

This goes on. I need some way of corresponding the songs with the genres and then display them in a list box called **lstPlayList** using Arrays

I have

```
strSongs(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
strGenre(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
dblLength(intCount) = Convert.ToDouble(objReader.ReadLine())
```

For storing every variable but I can't append songs to genres

Comment: What's your issue? Is there an exception? What are you expecting?

Comment: say the user selects the genre "Rock" from a combo box. My expectation is for the program to find "All You Need is Love-Beatles" and all other rock songs on file and display it to the list box.

Comment: Dont break up data related to a thing into multiple arrays.  [Classes and Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34164458/1070452) keep the data together and makes it easier to manage

Comment: put it in a datatable. That would be the easiest to manage

Comment: I agree with putting it into a datatable. You can then use LINQ to easily get all songs belonging to a genre

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having three separate arrays for one item, you could indeed as other commenters have said, create a database, but if you don't want to go that far try this.

Create a structure at the top of your Form's class definition list this :-

```
Structure Song
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Genre As String
    Dim Duration As Single
End Structure
```

This effectively creates a new Datatype.

Next create a list of this datatype like this :-

```
Dim Songs As New List(Of Song)
```

When you read your data from the file, instead of what you've included in your question, you can add the data to the list like this :-

```
    Dim newSong As Song
    newSong.Name = objReader.ReadLine()
    newSong.Genre = objReader.ReadLine()
    newSong.Duration = Convert.ToDouble(objReader.ReadLine())
```

Now that you have one list of all the data, you can search the list and return results as a new list of all the results. This is the function that does the searching and returning of a list :-

```
Private Function SearchSongsByGenre(searchGenre As String) As List(Of Song)
    Dim returnList As New List(Of Song)
    For Each searchSong As Song In Songs
        If searchSong.Genre = searchGenre Then
            returnList.Add(searchSong)
        End If
    Next
    Return returnList
End Function
```

To use it in another sub, just create a list in the sub called.. say.. SearchResults :-

```
Dim SearchResults As New List(of Song)
Searchresults = SearchSongsByGenre("Rock")
```

Now you have a list of all the Songs that have the genre **Rock**

A lot safer than searching an array and getting data from 3 arrays that could become desynchronised.