# SortCompare Event not Firing for DataGridView Dynamically Added to TabControl

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, event-handling

Use of the datatable as a source of data for the datagridview works very nicely, however, I can't get the Dgv_SortCompare event to be fired when a column is being sorted.  The main issue is that numeric values in (purely) numeric columns columns in the dgv values are being sorted as text, where e.g. 1211.6 is smaller than 89.7

```
In Button1:

Dim datagridview1 As New DataGridView
datagridview1.AutoSize = True
datagridview1.AutoResizeRows()
datagridview1.AutoResizeColumns()
datagridview1.ClearSelection()
DoubleBuffered(datagridview1, True)

datagridview1.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders)
Dim dgvColumnHeaderStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()
dgvColumnHeaderStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
datagridview1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dgvColumnHeaderStyle
datagridview1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
datagridview1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both
datagridview1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

datagridview1.Refresh()
datagridview1.VirtualMode = False

Dim dgv As New DGVCREATE(datagridview1, dataarray, columnheaders, rowheaders, InputFeatureNames, InputObjectNames)

TabControl2.SelectedTab = TabControl2.TabPages.Item(0)
TabControl2.TabPages(0).Controls.Clear()
AddHandler() datagridview1.SortCompare, AddressOf dgv_SortCompare
TabControl2.TabPages(0).Controls.Add(datagridview1)
AddHandler CType(TabControl2.TabPages(0).Controls(0), DataGridView).SortCompare, AddressOf Me.dgv_SortCompare



Public Class DGVCREATE

    Sub New(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByVal dataarray(,) As Object, ByVal columnheaders() As String, ByVal rowheaders() As String, ByVal FieldNames() As String, ByVal RowNames() As String)

        dgv.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing

        ' Create the output table.
        GetResultsTable(rxdataarray, columnheaders, rowheaders, FieldNames, RowNames)

        'new trial code
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        dgv.DataSource = Form1.MainDataTable
        dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill

        'Set Column FillWeight in very large DGVs in order to prevent exception related to “Sum of FillWeight exceeds 65000”

        For i As Integer = 0 To Form1.MainDataTable.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim Column As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            Column.Name = Form1.MainDataTable.Columns(i).ColumnName
            Column.DataPropertyName = Form1.MainDataTable.Columns(i).ColumnName
            Column.HeaderText = Form1.MainDataTable.Columns(i).ColumnName
            Column.FillWeight = 20
            Column.MinimumWidth = 20
            dgv.Columns.Add(Column)
        Next i

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
            If InputFeatureType(i + 1) = 1 Then
                dgv.Columns(i).ValueType = GetType(Int64)
                dgv.Columns(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            End If
            If InputFeatureType(i + 1) = 2 Then
                dgv.Columns(i).ValueType = GetType(Double)
                dgv.Columns(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            End If
            If InputFeatureType(i + 1) = 3 Then
                dgv.Columns(i).ValueType = GetType(Double)
                dgv.Columns(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            End If
            If InputFeatureType(i + 1) = 4 Then
                dgv.Columns(i).ValueType = GetType(String)
                dgv.Columns(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            End If
        Next i

        dgv.AutoSize = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetResultsTable(ByVal dataarray(,) As Object, ByVal columnheaders() As String, ByVal rowheaders() As String, ByVal fieldnames() As String, ByVal rownames() As String)
        Form1.MainDataTable.Clear()
        Form1.MainDataTable.Rows.Clear()
        Form1.MainDataTable.Columns.Clear()
        ' Loop through all process names.
        For j As Integer = 0 To UBound(columnheaders) - 1
            ' The current process name.
            ' Add the program name to our columns.
            Form1.MainDataTable.Columns.Add(fieldnames(j + 1))
            'Form1.MainDataTable.Columns.Add(fieldnames(j + 1))
            ' Keep adding rows until we have enough.
            Do While Form1.MainDataTable.Rows.Count < UBound(rowheaders)
                Form1.MainDataTable.Rows.Add()
            Loop
            ' Add each item to the cells in the column.
            For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(rowheaders) - 1
                Form1.MainDataTable.Rows(i)(j) = dataarray(i, j)
            Next i
        Next j
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cannot duplicate - what is in the DGV that it needs help being sorted?

Comment: The numeric values are being sorted as if they are string values, that is, 1,220.7 is being treated as less than 89.7.

Comment: I suspect the reason is because you are storing strings to it. You dont need to set the `ValueType` for each cell, just `dgv.Columns(n).ValueType = ...` to set the entire column. I am pretty sure you need to do that before you add any data.  `"D"` specifies a Date format, try "Nx" where x is the number of digits.  The "D" format should cause a `DataError` if it *is* a numeric column with numbers in it.  Given actual numbers the default sort should work fine.  Maybe show how it is created and populated

Comment: I added the full code with creation and populating.

Comment: You are doing a lot of things you dont need to.  Where does `dataArray()` come from? Why does the data need to go into an array before the DataTable?  `As Object` is almost always a bad idea - it boxes the real type and hides it.  Since you bind the DGV to the DT, it is going to ignore the DGV  `ValueType ` specified and use whatever type is in the DT.  Since those all got boxed, it uses `ToString()`. Put properly typed data in the datatable (use a class object {Int64, Double Double, String} as a DTO if you need to) then let the DGV generate the columns and all will work as intended.

Comment: Dataarray is read via binary from disk right before the datagridview is created.  Dataarray is also a mixture of purely text and purely numeric fields, since this is the common data format. (thus, dataarray can't be of type string or double).  If i know the format of each column in dataarray, can that be used to format the datatable columns(?) prior to boxing into the DGV?

Comment: Create a `DataItem` Class `{Int64, Double Double, String}` to replace dataarray.  Store them in a `List(Of DataItem)`.  Now you dont need a datatable - just use it as the DataSource. See [Using related data stored in a 2 dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34163827/1070452) for an example.  You can also get rid of `DGVCREATE`

Comment: Since I knew the format, the following resulted in format carry-through all the way to the DGV, resulting in appropriate sorts (this is for a numeric field): `If InputFeatureType(j + 1) = 1 Then Form1.MainDataTable.Columns.Add(fieldnames(j + 1), GetType(Double))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of unneeded code there.  First, you want to avoid boxing your data `As Object` because it prevents things like the DGV from seeing what type it is. A `DataTable` is perfectly capable of storing the typed data.  If you have to, you could create a class to act like a DTO:

```
Public Class DataItem
    Public Property Able As Int64
    Public Property Baker As Double
    Public Property Charlie As Double
    Public Property Delta As String
End Class
```

Since a `DataTable` can hold multiple types, use it in place of `DataArray` and avoid the data hopscotching its way there:

```
Private dtData As DataTable
...
' create it somewhere
dtData = New DataTable
dtData.Columns.Add("Able", GetType(Int64))
dtData.Columns.Add("Baker", GetType(Double))
dtData.Columns.Add("Chanrlie", GetType(Double))   ' aka Charlie
dtData.Columns.Add("Delta", GetType(String))
```

Fill it with data:

```
For n As Int32 = 0 To 999
    dr = dtData.NewRow

    dr(0) = RNG.Next()        ' random value
    dr(1) = RNG.NextDouble()  ' random 0.00 to 1.0
    dr(2) = RNG.Next(-19, 20) + RNG.NextDouble()  ' -19.xx to +19.xx
    dr(3) = RD.GetNames(2, 35)  ' 2 random names
    ' add new row:
    dtData.Rows.Add(dr)
Next
```

When it is filled, let the DGV create the columns for you - it will read the data types etc from the source:

```
dgv1.DataSource = dtData
For Each dc As DataGridViewColumn In dgv1.Columns
    Console.WriteLine(dc.ValueType)
Next
```

The DGV sees the types and will sort any of them correctly:

> System.Int64
>   System.Double
>   System.Double
>   System.String

[image]

Comment: Thanks Plutonix! This is wonderful.   Are you using the Mersenne Twister for `RNG`?  The `RNG.next()` looks like the C# sharp use of a random number after a vector is generated.

Comment: No, `RNG` is the standard NET `Random` Class and `Next` is a standard method.  `RD` is a random data generator though for the names (quick way to generate stuff for testing).  Most Mersenne implementations inherit from it so the methods have the same name.