# VB.NET How would I store multiple inputs in a single preset structure

Tags: vb.net

So I've been making a 'database' that would store different students ID's, names and grades.
And the problem I'm having is that the my structure has no 'depth' and I can only store one set of data inside it. How would I increase the capacity of my structure so I'm able to store more than 1 set of data? My code is this:

```
Structure record
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim fname As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim grade As String
End Structure
```

Comment: [Five Minute Guide to Classes and Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34163827/1070452) may be of interest

Answer (score 0):

Convert your struct to a class:

```
Class clsRecord

    public ID As Integer

    public fname As String

    public sName As String

    public grade As String
```

end class

Create a List to hold a collection of Record Classes

```
Dim lstRecords as List(Of clsRecord)
```

Create new instance of class clsRecord
    Dim someRecord as new clsRecord

Populate members
eg

```
someRecord.ID = 1
```

Add class to collection

```
lstRecord.Add(someRecord)
```

Repeat

Then loop through collection for each record

```
For Each xRecords in lstRecords

    'do something

Next
```

Comment: Why would I use class over struct?

Comment: @AnB [Structures and Classes (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a.aspx) and also [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx)