# Making a List(Of ...) from multiple form object

Tags: vb.net, list

So I'm trying to make a list of more than one type of object, which I done a research on and found out it's, but I also researched into structures and found I can possibly make a use of that instead, but it doesn't return itself as a list.

```
Imports WinText = System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Imports WinCombo = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

Public Class PSS      

    Public EntryItems = New List(Of Elements)

    Structure Elements
         Dim xSchool As WinCombo
         Dim xClass As WinCombo
         Dim xID As WinCombo
         Dim xName As WinText        
    End Structure
End Class
```

Edit: So on a form I have a set of ComboBoxes and TextBoxes (about 20 more than on the example here). I want to put them into a list so that when I will be retrieving their results, or getting their names for SQL references, or anything similar, I will be able put them into a loop, thus making the code more efficient and shorter to do.

Comment: `I'm trying to make a list of more than one type of object` your List contains a struct with multiple objects. `but it doesn't return itself as a list` with no return statement, how do you expect to return that list? Do you want to return it in a property, or a function? I guess the problem is you need to populate your list. Is that right?

Comment: **[Five Minute Intro To Classes and Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34164458/1070452)**

Comment: In short, I'd like to basically create a list of ComboBoxes and TextBoxes. My actual code is much more longer (and complicated) but I referred to return as in when I was testing it, the list was empty.

Comment: You dont need to `Imports` control types in a WinForms app.  Creating lists of controls is a bit odd compared to a List of data.  We have no idea *what* you are doing, just a glimmer of *how* you are trying to do something

Comment: @Plutonix ok, so on a form I have a set of ComboBoxes and TextBoxes (about 20 more than on the example here). I want to put them into a list so that when I will be retrieving their results, or getting their names for SQL references, or anything similar, I will be able put them into a loop, thus making the code more efficient and shorter to do.

Comment: You might consider a DataGridView since what you are describing is essentially a tedious way to provide that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, credits to MatSnow.

Taking his concept of `As Control` I was able to make a `List(Of Control)` which allowed me to make and add items to it.

```
Dim ControlList As New List(Of Control)
ControlList.Add(ComboBox1)
ControlList.Add(TextBox1)
'And so on
```

Answer (score 0):

`Structure` has similarities to `Class` and is not a list.
(Read more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/structures-and-classes))

You can create a `List(Of Structure)` but you need to populate it first, like djv stated already in comments.

```
Private Sub Populate()
    Dim list As New List(Of Elements)

    list.Add(New Elements)
    'Add as much Elements as you want
End Sub
```

---

Assuming your Controls are placed on a Form named `Form1`.

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Form1.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
        'Do whatever you want with the current TextBox
    ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
        Dim chk As ComboBox = DirectCast(ctrl, ComboBox)
        'Do whatever you want with the current ComboBox
    End If
Next
```

Comment: In short, I'd like to basically create a list of ComboBoxes and TextBoxes. My actual code is much more longer (and complicated) but my target is just to make a list from different types and innitialy I thought to make a structure that would consist ComboBoxes and TextBoxes and then put those in a list but clearly that's not the way.

Comment: Is it possible if I used `Dim ControlList As New List(Of Control)`?
Edit v1.2 and then populate it by using `ControlList.Add(exampleTextOrComboBox)`?