# Reading a file in and outputting to two listboxes

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm using `Imports System.IO` and `StreamReader` inside a Windows Forms App.

I am trying to take a file, read it in, and output it into two listboxes. The text file is formatted like this.

```
Blue, 23.7
Green, 60.1
Black, 45.3
```

I want to output colours that have a higher value than 50 into one listbox, and the ones lower into another. So far all I've done is output the whole list into a textbox. The code for that looks like this:

```
srTextFile = File.OpenText(dataFile)

Do While srTextFile.EndOfStream = False
    'read file by line, use the comma as a splitter
    thisFile = srTextFile.ReadLine().Split(",")
    For i As Integer = 0 To thisFile.GetUpperBound(0)
        txtFileDisplay.AppendText(thisFile(i) &vbTab)
    Next
    txtFileDisplay.AppendText(vbCrLf)
Loop
```

I'm completely new to reading in files. I really don't know what I'm doing. I'm pretty new to arrays as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include any code you have tried?

Comment: Paired arrays like that are an anti-pattern... something to avoid. **MUCH** better to create Class and read into a single array or List of that class type. Also... are these exact example of the data? Is there _any chance at all_ the "identifier" field could itself contain a comma?

Comment: You can edit your question in order to add it.

Comment: You may find a [Five minute Guide to Collections and Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34164458/1070452) useful

Comment: The Collections and Classes is cool. Thanks WelcomeOverflow

Comment: If I were to use a class, how would I go about putting the colour into one category of the class, and the number into another subcategory.

Comment: I would also recommend that you never use controls as your primary place to store your data. User input and errors in your code can cause corruption or loss.

Answer (score 1):

By using a class, you can create objects containing the color names as well as the double value and add those to the listboxes.

```
Public Class ColorValue
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Double

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Name} ({Value})"
    End Function
End Class
```

Note that I've overridden `ToString`, because `ListBox` uses it to display a text for each item.

Now, you can add colors to the listboxes like this

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(dataFile)
    Dim parts As String() = line.Split(","c)
    If parts.Length = 2 Then 'If line is well-shaped.
        Dim value As Double
        Double.TryParse(Trim(parts(1)), value) 'Gets 0 into value if conversion fails.
        Dim color = New ColorValue With {.Name = parts(0), .Value = value}
        If value > 50.0 Then
            listBox1.Items.Add(color)
        Else
            listBox2.Items.Add(color)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Now, you can get a color value back with

```
Dim c As ColorValue = DirectCast(listBox1.SelectedItem, ColorValue)
Dim n As String = c.Name
Dim v As Double = c.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `System.IO.File` Class to do this

1. Simply read the text file into a string
2. Split the string into lines
3. Split the lines into arrays
4. Parse the strings into doubles
5. Compare the doubles and get values greater than 50 into a seperate listbox

You can write your code like this:

```
 For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("Your file here")
     Dim Spl() AS String = Split(line, ",")
     'Convert string value to integer
     Dim myNum As Double = Double.Parse(Spl(1))'The number is the second item in the array
     If myNum < 50.0 Then
          'Add to your first Listbox here using
          'Listbox.Add(myNum)
     Else
          'Add to your second Listbox here using
          'Listbox.Add(myNum)
     End If
 Next
```

Comment: First I want to say thanks, this is really helpful! Is it possible to immediately read the file into myLines() without needing to read it all into a long string first?

Comment: @user10778077 i have edited the post. You can now read directly into myLines()

Comment: You can even skip reading the lines into `myLines()` by using `For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("file.txt")`. `ReadLines` does not store the lines in an intermediate collection. Instead, it reads the file as you iterate with `For Each`.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have made changes to the answer